# Alternative for r's Exponential smoothing state space model in python/scikit/numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

In R we have one good forecasting model like:

```
ets(y, model="ZZZ", damped=NULL, alpha=NULL, beta=NULL, gamma=NULL, 

phi=NULL, additive.only=FALSE, lambda=NULL, 

lower=c(rep(0.0001,3), 0.8), upper=c(rep(0.9999,3),0.98), 

opt.crit=c("lik","amse","mse","sigma","mae"), nmse=3, 

bounds=c("both","usual","admissible"), ic=c("aicc","aic","bic"),

restrict=TRUE, allow.multiplicative.trend=FALSE, use.initial.values=FALSE, ...)
```

In this method if we assign any variable, it  automatically gets *season type,trend & error type* like  `model="ZZZ"/"AMA"/"MMZ"` and some of the factors are auto adjusted to get accurate results.

- In python do we have anything similar to `ets` in either
  pandas/numpy/scipy/scikit?

  **By my research:**
  [`Ewma`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.ewma.html) in pandas is similar, but we need to hardcode all the parameters to fixed ones.
  In Holtwinter we need to write detailed methods for all the trend and season types.
- So instead of that do we have any ready-made functions which takes
  dataframes as input and provides forecasting values, without writing
  any inner functions for parameters ourselves?
- Any Fine tuned regression models scikit/statsmodels?

Comment: Here are a couple of references on the approach taken by the R package: https://www.otexts.org/fpp/7/7 http://robjhyndman.com/talks/ABS1.pdf .  So far I have not found a python package that implements the complete state space framework.

Comment: Could you just use the R tools from Python via the `rpy2` package?

Comment: @mfripp Yes, I could call R from python, but I'd prefer to use python directly, if I can!

Comment: The statsmodels state space models look promising: http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/statespace.html In particular, the custom models function: http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/statespace.html#custom-state-space-models

Comment: This is promising, but also incomplete: https://github.com/mcskinner/ets

Comment: This also looks promising: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/1287

Comment: Also promising: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/1489

Comment: Are you working with daily data?  This may be taking too few parameters, but [facebook's prophet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fbprophet/) or see [here](https://facebookincubator.github.io/prophet/) may be a good answer?

Comment: @RafZ Thanks for the suggestion.  Prophet does look very promising; I'll check it out!

Answer (score 7):

After searching around a bit, I haven't found anything that seems really promising as an `ets` alternative for python. There are some tries though: [StatsModels](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html) and [pycast's Forecasting methods](http://pythonhosted.org/pycast/methods/forecastingmethods.html), which you can check if they suit your needs.

One option you can use to workaround the missing implementation is to run an R script from python using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html) module. There is a very good article on how to do this [here](http://www.mango-solutions.com/wp/2015/10/integrating-python-and-r-part-ii-executing-r-from-python-and-vice-versa/).

**In order to do the later:**

1. You need to create an R script (ex. `my_forecast.R`), which will
   **calculate** (using `ets`) and **print** the forecasts on a file, or on `stdout` (with the `cat()` command), in order to use them after the script
   runs.
2. You can run the R script from a python script as follows:

   ```
   import subprocess

   # You need to define the command that will run the Rscript from the subprocess
   command = 'Rscript'
   path2script = 'path/to/my_forecast.R'
   cmd = [command, path2script]

   # Option 1: If your script prints to a file
   subprocess.run(cmd)
   f = open('path/to/created/file', 'r')
   (...Do stuff from here...)

   # Option 2: If your script prints to stdout
   forecasts = subprocess.check_output(cmd, universal_newlines=True)
   (...Do stuff from here...)
   ```

   You can also add arguments to your `cmd`, which will be utilized by your Rscript as command line arguments, as follows:

   ```
   args = [arg0, arg1, ...]

   cmd = [command, path2script] + args 
   Then pass cmd to the subprocess
   ```

---

**EDIT:**

I found an exemplary series of articles on the Holt-Winters Forecasting: [part1](https://grisha.org/blog/2016/01/29/triple-exponential-smoothing-forecasting/), [part2](https://grisha.org/blog/2016/02/16/triple-exponential-smoothing-forecasting-part-ii/) and [part3](https://grisha.org/blog/2016/02/17/triple-exponential-smoothing-forecasting-part-iii/). Besides the easy to comprehend analysis in those articles, **Gregory Trubetskoy** (the author) has provided the code he developed:

**Initial trend:**

```
def initial_trend(series, slen):
    sum = 0.0
    for i in range(slen):
        sum += float(series[i+slen] - series[i]) / slen
    return sum / slen

# >>> initial_trend(series, 12)
# -0.7847222222222222
```

**Initial Seasonal Components:**

```
def initial_seasonal_components(series, slen):
    seasonals = {}
    season_averages = []
    n_seasons = int(len(series)/slen)
    # compute season averages
    for j in range(n_seasons):
        season_averages.append(sum(series[slen*j:slen*j+slen])/float(slen))
    # compute initial values
    for i in range(slen):
        sum_of_vals_over_avg = 0.0
        for j in range(n_seasons):
            sum_of_vals_over_avg += series[slen*j+i]-season_averages[j]
        seasonals[i] = sum_of_vals_over_avg/n_seasons
    return seasonals

# >>> initial_seasonal_components(series, 12)
# {0: -7.4305555555555545, 1: -15.097222222222221, 2: -7.263888888888888,
#  3: -5.097222222222222,  4: 3.402777777777778,   5: 8.069444444444445,  
#  6: 16.569444444444446,  7: 9.736111111111112,   8: -0.7638888888888887,
#  9: 1.902777777777778,  10: -3.263888888888889, 11: -0.7638888888888887}
```

**Finally the algorithm:**

```
def triple_exponential_smoothing(series, slen, alpha, beta, gamma, n_preds):
    result = []
    seasonals = initial_seasonal_components(series, slen)
    for i in range(len(series)+n_preds):
        if i == 0: # initial values
            smooth = series[0]
            trend = initial_trend(series, slen)
            result.append(series[0])
            continue
        if i >= len(series): # we are forecasting
            m = i - len(series) + 1
            result.append((smooth + m*trend) + seasonals[i%slen])
        else:
            val = series[i]
            last_smooth, smooth = smooth, alpha*(val-seasonals[i%slen]) + (1-alpha)*(smooth+trend)
            trend = beta * (smooth-last_smooth) + (1-beta)*trend
            seasonals[i%slen] = gamma*(val-smooth) + (1-gamma)*seasonals[i%slen]
            result.append(smooth+trend+seasonals[i%slen])
    return result

# # forecast 24 points (i.e. two seasons)
# >>> triple_exponential_smoothing(series, 12, 0.716, 0.029, 0.993, 24)
# [30, 20.34449316666667, 28.410051892109554, 30.438122252647577, 39.466817731253066, ...
```

You can place those in a file, ex: `holtwinters.py` inside a folder with the following structure:

```
forecast_folder
|
└── __init__.py
|
└── holtwinters.py
```

From here on, this is a python module which you can place inside every project structure you want and use it anywhere inside that project, simply by importing it.

Comment: I'd really like to avoid calling out to an R sub-process.  I appreciate the detailed answer, but I set the bounty because I was hoping to find something in python.

Comment: At the moment there are the tries that I have linked in the beginning of my answer and @jseabold is the initial developer of StatsModels so if you query him he may be able to shed  some light on the matter!

Comment: I have added a ready-made way to do Holt Winters forecasting in python

Comment: I'm giving you the bounty because you put a lot of effort into answering the question, but this still isn't really what I'm looking for.  If someone in the future finds (or creates) an implementation all 30 of Rob Hyndmans state-space exponential smoothing models, I'll be happy to make and award another bounty: https://www.otexts.org/fpp/7/7

Comment: @Zach is my answer more looking for?

Answer (score 6):

ETS is now available in python as part of the Statsmodels' most recent [release](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/milestone/10). Here is a simple example of its use:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing

# make our own periodic data
# 3 weeks of hourly data
m = 24
days = 21
x = np.array(range(days * m)) / (m / 2 / np.pi)
st = 4 * np.sin(x)
lt = np.linspace(0, 15, days * m)
bt = 100
e = np.random.normal(scale=0.5, size=x.shape)

# make the ts we wish to forecast
y = lt + st + bt + e

# our guessed parameters
alpha = 0.4
beta = 0.2
gamma = 0.01

# initialise model
ets_model = ExponentialSmoothing(y, trend='add', seasonal='add', 
seasonal_periods=24)
ets_fit = ets_model.fit(smoothing_level=alpha, smoothing_slope=beta,
smoothing_seasonal=gamma)

# forecast p hours ahead
p_ahead = 48
yh = ets_fit.forecast(p_ahead)

# plot the y, y_smoothed and y_hat ts'
plt.plot(y, label='y')
plt.plot(ets_fit.fittedvalues, label='y_smooth')
plt.plot(range(days * m, days * m + p_ahead),yh, label='y_hat')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here are more [examples](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/examples/notebooks/exponential_smoothing.ipynb) in notebook form.

Finally, here is the [source code](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/de9a7da489e642847e7b025951cc4bb6d081564b/statsmodels/tsa/holtwinters.py), should you wish to take a look over it.